# Minimum EC2 Requirements for a stable Wordpress site

Tags: hosting, amazon

I have had a frustrating experience with website hosting companies and am looking to migrate my Wordpress site to something which offers better reliability and more technical control.

I have some limited experience with AWS (Deploying an instance; setting up a LAMP stack etc) and EC2 seems like a possible solution, provided the costs make sense.

Expected traffic / bandwidth is low; sub 1000 hits a month with few files greater than 300kB.

- Would a 'small' (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/hosting) EC2 instance be sufficient for my needs?
- Any gotchas I should look out for?
- Any alternative hosting suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Having gathered advice from various sources, DigitalOcean seems to be a better fit for my needs than AWS, in that they provide a one-click Wordpress install and simple pricing at reasonable rates.

At this point I don't have enough first-hand experience to recommend DigitalOcean as a Wordpress host, but if you have similar requirements they seem to be worth considering. I will follow-up here with any issues I encounter.